# How to assign variable value as new column value in pyspark data-frame?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am assigning value to a variable which is fetched from a dataframe as follows :

```
    dfScore =  spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("data.csv")

    level = dfScore.where((col("Name") == "Rule1")).select(dfScore ["level"])
```

Then i have another dataframe to which i have to add this level variable value :

```
dfJson =  spark.read.format("json").load("/mnt/coi/Rule/Rule1.json")

 ScoreCal1 = dfJson.where((dfJson["Amount"] > 20000)).select(dfJson["*"])
```

So i want to create a new column in dataframe and assign level variable as new column value. I am doing that in following way but no success :

```
ScoreCal1 = ScoreCal1.withColumn("Level",lit(level)))
```

> How to assign a variable as new column value in pyspark dataframe ?

Answer (score 2):

from your code i have noticed, level seems to be dataframe not a variable. Hence it throws error.

Since you specified as below, it returns dataframe only not variable:

```
level =dfScore .where((col("DataField") == "Amount")).select(dfScore ["level"])
```

However i understand from your code, that you want to assign value for a new column "Level" with value of old column level, if it satisfies following condition col("DataField") == "Amount" else Null. If it so you, can write your code using when condition as below:

```
ScoreCal1 = ScoreCal1.withColumn("Level",when(col("DataField") == "Amount",dfScore ["level"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to assign level to new Dataframe . Updated the code in question

Comment: since level is a dataframe, you cannot add it is a column. lit works only if you have single value as it add's the same value in all rows. Instead, you can use join operation on both dataframes if they have common_id and then do perform required analytics.

Comment: yeah i did the same used a lit and provided string value to it from level dataframe and worked .